# How can I insert text via button click at the cursor in the most recent textbox used?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with multiple text boxes and a set of buttons.  Using the Javascript below, I am able to click a button and insert text into one of the named boxes.

Is it possible to insert text into the most recent/active textbox when a button is clicked?

Currently I have this, but it's using the specific ID of a text box, rather than the most recently used/active one;

```
   $( 'input[type=button]' ).on('click', function(){
      var cursorPos = $('#my_text_box').prop('selectionStart');
      var v = $('#my_text_box').val();
      var textBefore = v.substring(0,  cursorPos );
      var textAfter  = v.substring( cursorPos, v.length );
      $('#my_text_box').val( textBefore+ $(this).val() +textAfter );
    });
```

Example on JSFiddle for more clarity;

http://jsfiddle.net/bd1xf0sj/1/

The idea being that depending upon which text box you're in when the button is clicked, instead of using the ID of a certain textbox. The idea being that the buttons can be clicked and any textbox can be used.

Comment: What determines the active field in your case?

Comment: Ideally the text box that the cursor was in when the button was clicked

Answer (score 7):

You can create a variable to store the most recent textbox and update it whenever a textbox is focused like this:

```
let currentInput = $('#text1');
$(document).on('focus', 'textarea', function() {
  currentInput = $(this);
})
```

Then use this variable to update text just like you're doing with your `#my_text_box`:

```
$( 'input[type=button]' ).on('click', function(){
  let cursorPos = currentInput.prop('selectionStart');
  let v = currentInput.val();
  let textBefore = v.substring(0,  cursorPos );
  let textAfter  = v.substring( cursorPos, v.length );
  currentInput.val( textBefore + $(this).val() + textAfter );
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hsqnzkf/1/)

**Update**: Some modification to preserve the cursor position after insert text:

```js
let currentInput = document.getElementById('text1');
$(document).on('focus', 'textarea', function() {
    currentInput = this;
})

$( 'input[type=button]' ).on('click', function(){
  let cursorPos = currentInput.selectionStart;
  let v = currentInput.value;
  let textBefore = v.substring(0,  cursorPos );
  let textAfter  = v.substring( cursorPos, v.length );
  currentInput.value = textBefore + this.value + textAfter;
  
  cursorPos += this.value.length;
  currentInput.focus();
  currentInput.setSelectionRange(cursorPos, cursorPos);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <textarea id="text1" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
    <textarea id="text2" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
    <textarea id="text3" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
    <textarea id="text4" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="one" />
    <input type="button" value="two" />
    <input type="button" value="three" />
</form>
```

Comment: A very clever solution, you can also mark all the elements using a special class so you can insert in textarea but also in input type text.

Comment: Would be great if you caan you insert the modifications directly into the stack overflow answer? that would be beneficial for the reader

Comment: @GM I've added it.

Answer (score 1):

You can track the current state of the inputs focus using a `data-attribute` set to a boolean value `true` or `false` within the input elements HTML.

Start by defining the first `data-current` attribute to ***true***, every other one to ***false***. This way there is a default setting to ***true***. Then we run an event to check ***focus*** on the ***textarea*** elements. If the ***textarea*** is ***focused*** on, we remove all instances of the selectors `data-current` values and set them all to **false**, we then set our current event targets `data-current` value to ***true***.

Then on the *click* event for the **buttons**, we check our ***textarea*** element *iterating* over them and run a *conditional* that checks their `data-current` *value*, we find the one set to ***true*** and then assign its *value* to the *buttons value*.

```js
$('textarea').focus(e => {
  let $this = e.target;
  $('textarea').each((i, el) => {
    if(el.dataset.current === 'true'){
      el.dataset.current = false;
    }
    $this.dataset.current = true;
  })
  console.log(`Selected TextArea's id: ${$this.id}`)
})

$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
  const $this = $(this);
  const $ta = $('textarea');
  $ta.each((i, el) => {
  
    // do not retain previously set values when a new button
    // is selected on a different focused textarea
    el.dataset.current === 'true' ? 
      el.value = $this.val() :
      el.value = '';       
/*  
    // retain previously set values in TA's on button click
    // when new textarea is focused
    el.dataset.current === 'true' ?
      el.value = $this.val() : null;    
*/
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea id="text1" data-current="true" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
  <textarea id="text2" data-current="false" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
  <textarea id="text3" data-current="false" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="one" />
  <input type="button" data-current="false" value="two" />
  <input type="button" data-current="false" value="three" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks that's an interesting approach, in this case this can be easily extended to threat textarea and also input text as possible candidates for insertion at the same time making  another for loop for input text.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a simple and fun exercise to solve, there are many approaches to solve this particular problem, though I will suggest mine.

Here's the link to solved [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tygrbqp9/) example.

Explanation:

Step 1: Add `focus` event listener on all `textarea`.

Step 2: On `textarea` focused, remove the class `last-focused` from existing `last-focused.textarea` elements.

Step 3: Add `last-focused` class to currently focused `textarea` element.

Step 4: Add `click` listener on `button`

Step 5: On `button` clicked, select `last-focused.textarea` element, and replace its content with the button's value.

Note: we can use any name for class, just given  the name as `last-focused`, as it relates to the current context.

HTML:

```
<form>
  <textarea id="text1" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
  <textarea id="text2" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="one" />
  <input type="button" value="two" />
  <input type="button" value="three" />
</form>
```

JS + JQuery:

```
// Step 1
$('textarea').on('focus', function() {
    // Step 2
    $('textarea.last-focused').removeClass('last-focused');
    // Step 3
    $(this).addClass('last-focused');
});

// Step 4
$('input[type=button]').on('click', function() { 
    // Step 5
    $('textarea.last-focused').html($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can track last focused input element with focus event of textarea elements and append last active element's value when button clicked:

```
var mostrecent=$('textarea')[0];
$('textarea').each(function(i,item){
  $(item).focus(function(){
    mostrecent=this;
  });
});
```

```js
var mostrecent=$('textarea')[0];
$('textarea').each(function(i,item){
  $(item).focus(function(){
    mostrecent=this;
  });
});
$( 'input[type=button]' ).on('click', function(){
            var cursorPos = $('#text1').prop('selectionStart');
            var v = $('#text1').val();
            var textBefore = v.substring(0,  cursorPos );
            var textAfter  = v.substring( cursorPos, v.length );
            $(mostrecent).val( textBefore+ $(this).val() +textAfter );
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <textarea id="text1" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
    <textarea id="text2" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="one" />
    <input type="button" value="two" />
    <input type="button" value="three" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook into [form events](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) to mark the most recent input as "recent" (using some class) and unmark all other inputs. On click modify the "recent" input.

Most likely you'll need `onfocus`, but might be `onchange` depending on your specific use case.

Answer (score -4):

The currently selected field is document.activeElement.

Comment: The current selected field will become the button that you are pressing, hence this answer is not correct.

Comment: All right: function activeElement() { var fe = getSelection().focusNode; if (!fe) return null; if (fe.nodeType==3) fe=fe.parentNode; return fe.closest("div[contenteditable],input,textarea"); }