# How to select the previously "current active" element? Is there document.hadFocus?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, pseudo-element

How do I select the one of many input elements that had the cursor in it a split second before  clicking a button to add something to the (previously) active input text box? Is there any method `document.hadFocus`? Can I get the id of the input using `onFocusOut` and pass it to my function?
I've seen many solutions in JQuery but can anyone do it in vanilla JS?

```
function insertAtCursor(newText, el = document.activeElement) {
    //getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus(); 
    const start = el.selectionStart;
    const end = el.selectionEnd;
    const text = el.value;
    const before = text.substring(0, start);
    const after  = text.substring(end, text.length);
    el.value = (before + newText + after);
    el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = start + newText.length;
    el.focus();
}
```

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68176703/11711316

Comment: thanks @Cuong, that looks perfect... if I knew JQ. I'm looking for solution in vanilla JS.

Comment: My idea is *You can create a variable to store the most recent textbox and update it whenever a textbox is focused*. You just need to use js to bind focus event instead of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by replacing the `onclick` `eventListener` of my `button` (for adding text to an input box...)
with a `focusout` `eventlistener` on the previous element (the input box).
That way the event was tied to the input box and had everything I needed.
`e.relatedTarget` is the opposite of what I needed ("`hadFocus`"). It is "what element (if any) is getting the new focus of this `focusout` event?" The `if` statement uses this `relatedTarget` to make sure that the focus was lost to the button.
`this` is tied to the inputBox that "hadFocus" when the button was pressed.

```
inputBox.addEventListener( "focusout", insertAtCursor )
function insertAtCursor( event ){
    if ( e.relatedTarget?.parentElement?.classList?.value == "buttonSet" ){
      const text    = this.value;                
      const start   = this.selectionStart;       
      const end     = this.selectionEnd;         
      const wordId  = this.id;                   
      const newTextToAddFromButton = e.relatedTarget.innerText;
      ...
     }
 }
```